# Calculate % Change Avoiding NA's, By Group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(person = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", 
"d", "e", "f"), data = c(4.51646448148296, 6.50396548317118, 
NA, 9.84425670640439, NA, NA, 1.67850554309375, NA, 2.06950894895984, 
4.69548965710482, 5.12795074939009, 0.209845957108408, 6.47290211779118, 
6.26481009615426, NA, NA, 5.24543093106204, 4.75242871394851, 
6.8182202925863, NA, 5.3162641705813, 6.05862341995543, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like this

```
  person     data
1       a 4.516464
2       a 6.503965
3       a       NA
4       a 9.844257
5       a       NA
6       a       NA
7       a 1.678506
8       b       NA
9       b 2.069509
10      b 4.695490
11      b 5.127951
12      c 0.209846
13      c 6.472902
14      c 6.264810
15      c       NA
16      c       NA
17      c 5.245431
18      c 4.752429
19      d 6.818220
20      d       NA
21      d 5.316264
22      e 6.058623
23      f       NA
```

I'm trying to be able to calculate the percent change from the latest and second latest entry in the `data` column based on `person`. The entries are logged from first to latest by person (i.e., row 1 was person A's first entry, and row 7 was their latest entry).

I have tried various combinations of the following code with no luck:

```
df %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(percChange = c(rep(NA, ((df %>% count(person))[2]) - 
                              length(((na.omit(data) - lag(na.omit(data)))/na.omit(data)*100))), 
                        (na.omit(data) - lag(na.omit(data)))/na.omit(data)*100)) %>%
  summarise(max = max(na.omit(data)),
            avg = mean(na.omit(data)),
            lastPercChange = last(na.omit(percChange)))
```

The desired output would look like this, with example calculation of the last % change:

```
 person     max    avg        lastPercChange                                                                       
1 a         9.84   5.64       33.93138    (1.678506-9.844257)/1.678506 * 100 
2 b         5.13   3.96       8.433407    (5.127951-4.695490)/5.127951 * 100 
3 c         6.47   4.59       -10.37368   (4.752429-5.245431)/4.752429 * 100
4 d         6.82   6.07       14.66658    (5.316264-6.818220)/5.316264 * 100 
5 e         6.06   6.06       NA          (since only 1 observation)                 
6 f      -Inf    NaN          NA          (since only 1 observation)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For person `a` the calculation should be `(1.678506-9.844257)/1.678506 * 100` ? and for person `d` `(5.316264 - 6.818220)/5.316264 * 100`

Comment: Yes, sorry person `a` should be changed to that. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity I would drop all the `NA` rows first then it is easy to calculate the values that you want. Function `nth(..)` or `head`/`tail` can help us provide last and second last values.

If a `person` has all the `NA` values it would be dropped completely from the output to keep it intact we do a `right_join` with the original data.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!is.na(data)) %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  summarise(max = max(data), 
            avg = mean(data), 
            lastPercChange = (nth(data,-1) - nth(data,-2))/nth(data, -1) *100)%>%
  right_join(df %>% distinct(person), by = 'person')

# person   max   avg lastPercChange
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 a       9.84  5.64        -486.  
#2 b       5.13  3.96           8.43
#3 c       6.47  4.59         -10.4 
#4 d       6.82  6.07         -28.3 
#5 e       6.06  6.06          NA   
#6 f      NA    NA             NA
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a follow up to this: if there was an extra column called `data2` with some similar variation of values and NA's, would the best thing be to do `...filter(!is.na(data), !is.na(data2))...` and then in summarise have max/max2 etc?

Comment: No, in that case you would need a different approach. If you do `filter(!is.na(data), !is.na(data2))` then it will only drop rows where both of them are `NA`. We need to deal with each column separately. You may ask a new question if you have trouble implementing it.